Semiring with a unique left ideal
For the purpose of this post, a semiring is an algebraic structure satisfying the axioms of a (unital) ring except the existence of additive inverses.
Recall the equivalent characterizations of a local ring $R$:
(1) $R$ has a unique maximal left ideal;
(2) $R$ has a unique maximal right ideal;
(3) $1\ne 0$ in $R$, and $R\setminus R^\times$ (the nonunits) is an additive submonoid (equivalently, $\forall x, y \in R, x + y\in R^\times\to x\in R^\times$ or $y \in R^\times$);
(4) $1\ne 0$ in $R$, and $\forall x,y\in R, x+y=1\implies x\in R^\times$ or $y\in R^\times$.
It is not hard to see the implications $(3)\iff (4)$ and $(3)\implies (1)(2)$ continue to hold for a semiring $R$. The implications $(1)\implies (2)$ (and by symmetry $(2)\implies(1)$) and $(1)(2)\implies (3)$ work for commutative semirings and for rings, but the proofs I have do not generalize to all semirings.
A key fact used in the proofs is that if $R$ has a unique maximal ideal $I$, then $I$ is also a right ideal. This is trivial assuming commutativity, and if $R$ is a ring, then the preimage of a maximal submodule of an $R$-module $N$ under an $R$-linear map of $M\to N$ is either a maximal $R$-submodule of $M$ or $M$ itself (proof). (This can fail even for commutative semirings: the preimage of the maximal ideal $0\subset\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{N}$ under the $\mathbb{N}$-linear map $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (reduction modulo 2) is $2\mathbb{N}$, which is not maximal; in fact $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$ is the unique maximal ideal in $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ is "local".) Applying this to right multiplication by $r\in R$ (denoted $\rho_r$), we see that $\rho_r^{-1}(I)$ is either $I$ or $R$, so $I\subseteq\rho_r^{-1}(I)$ and $Ir=\rho_r(I)\subseteq I$ for all $r \in R$, which shows $I$ is a right ideal.
Since $I$ is the unique maximal left ideal, every $x\in R\setminus I$ has a left inverse $y$; $y$ can't lie in $I$ since $I$ is a proper right ideal, so $y$ also has a left inverse, which implies $x$ and $y$ are both units (and are inverse to each other). So all elements outside of $I$ are units, which shows $I$ is also the unique maximal right ideal, establishing $(1)\implies(2)$. Since elements in $I$ must be nonunits, we see that $I$ consists exactly of the nonunits, so the nonunits form an additive submonoid, establishing $(1)\implies(3)$.
I am curious whether it could indeed happen for a semiring $R$ to possess a unique maximal left ideal $I$ that is not a right ideal. Assuming this happens, we have $Ir \not\subseteq I$ for some $r\in R$ and therefore $Ir=R$ because $Ir$ is a left ideal but is not contained in the unique maximal ideal. In particular, right multiplication by $r$ is surjective
and we have a strictly decreasing chain of left ideals $\dots\subsetneq\rho_r^{-2}(I)\subsetneq\rho_r^{-1}(I)\subsetneq I\subsetneq R$, so $R$ can't be Artinian. $Ir=R$ also shows $I$ can't be contained in any maximal (or any proper) right ideal, so if $R$ also has a unique maximal right ideal $J$, then $I$ and $J$ are incomparable; but maybe $R$ could have multiple maximal right ideals?
The proof of $(3)\implies(1)$ for semirings goes as follows: suppose for contradiction that $R$ has two different maximal left ideals $I_1$ and $I_2$, then $I_1+I_2=R$ and we can find $x\in I_1$ and $y\in I_2$ such that $x+y=1$. By (3), at least one of $x$ and $y$ is a unit, so they can't be contained in proper left ideal $I_1$ or $I_2$, contradiction. So if we assume (3), then $R$ has a unique maximal left ideal $I$ (consisting of elements without left inverse) and a unique maximal right ideal $J$ (consisting of elements without right inverse), and $I\cup J$ (the nonunits) is also a submonoid and therefore equals $I+J$. If $I$ and $J$ are subtractive (which is the case if $R$ is a ring, in which case they are subgroups), one can then show that one of $I$ and $J$ contains the other, so $I$ must be a right ideal and $I=J$ by the previous paragraph. But we are only assuming $R$ is a semiring; could it happen that (1)(2)(3) all hold but neither of the unique maximal left/right ideals is two-sided?
Any idea or reference is appreciated.
